# how to use filter() queryset without use loop here

Tags: django, list, loops, filter, django-queryset

i want avoid using queryset inside loop
cuz that hit database a lot
i have to list

```
Degreyid: [1, 3, 2, 3]
companyid: [2, 2, 2, 1]
```

i want use filtering in conjunction:
-i want filter for object have **Degreyid:1** and **companyid:2** and seconde test should be **Degreyid:3** and **companyid:2**.......... **Degreyid:3** and **companyid:1** .

i dont want use loop like this :

```
    i=0
    list=[]
    while i < len(listilam):
       ddegrycomp = DegreyCompany.objects.filter(withdegrey=Degreyid[i], company=companyid[i])
       i+=1
```

there is any way to use filter with two list in parallel ??

***note**:*
using : `.filter(withdegrey__in=Degreyid, company__in=companyid)` dont help here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can retrieve the elements with:

```
from django.db.models import Q

q_filter = Q(
    *[Q(withdegrey=x, company=y)
      for x, y in zip(Degreyid, companyid)],
    _connector=Q.OR
)
items = DegreyCompany.objects.filter(q_filter)
```

Here we construct a `Q` object. This is a filter *expression*, but we do *not* query with the loop. Then we thus retrieve the elements in one *single* query.

Comment: i got error when use ur queryset pls take look on the picteur

Comment: @SalimFh: there is a comma missing after the end of the list comprehension, fixed.

Comment: its work and its slove the problem .. thnxs a lot for ur help
i will try studing about Q this look solve a lot problem in lookup

Comment: Is there any way to slice for each query?