# Django Filtering A For Loop with 2 Parameters

Tags: django, django-orm, django-filter

I've built a notification system that allows a user to sign up for custom notifications (`Notification`) that fire based on their chosen parameter and threshold value from another model (`Report`).  My `models.py` looks like this:

```
class Report(models.Model):
    field1 = models.FloatField()
    field2 = models.FloatField()
    field3 = models.FloatField()
    ...

class Notification(models.Model):
    threshold_field = models.CharField()  # would store field1, field2, field3, etc from Report
    threshold_value = models.FloatField()  # the value corresponding to threshold_field that would trigger the notification
```

I'm trying to write a database query that would get all `Notification` that meet the criteria for triggering a notification given a `Report` or `Report` queryset.  However, I can't figure out how to pair all possible `threshold_field` and `threshold_value` within the query.  The ugliest possible solution that would work would be something like this:

```
report = Report.objects.first()  # get the report to query
all_fields = Report._meta.get_fields()  # all field choices from Report
all_querysets = []
for field in all_fields:  # loop through all fields, i.e. field1, field2, field3
    qs = Notification.objects.filter(
        threshold_field=field,
        threshold_value__gte=getattr(report, field)  # get the value stored in the field
    )
    all_querysets.append(qs)
```

This is ugly, but this isn't a horrible solution given that there are only ~20 fields in my production `Report`.  However, is there a better way to filter `Notification` without the `for` loop?  I know this would be possible if I only needed to query 1 field in `Notification`, but the stumbling point here is that both `threshold_field` AND `threshold_value` rely on the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution thanks in part to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64508652/how-to-use-filter-queryset-without-use-loop-here).  You can use a preprepared `Q` query to enforce a conditional OR statement across multiple fields that pass 2 criteria:

```
from django.db.models import Q

q_filter = Q(
        *[Q(threshold_field=field.name, threshold_value__gte=getattr(Report, field.name)) for field in
          Report._meta.get_fields()], _connector=Q.OR
    )  # complex filter to pair threshold field and threshold

return Notification.objects.filter(q_filter)
```